# React: Class method isn't always being ran?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a class component which loads a list of applications from an external API. It then runs an additional request for each application to ping it.

It fetches the applications fine. However, it only sometimes pings the applications (calls checkPing).

Here is the component:

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";

class Applications extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor() {
        super({});

        this.state = {
            applications: []
        }
    }

    async checkPing(applicationId : bigint) {
        //
    }

    async getApplications() {
        var component = this;

        await axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/applications')
            .then(async function (response) {
                await component.setState({
                    applications: response.data,
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            })
            .finally(function () {
                // always executed
            });

        for (let i = 0; i < component.state.applications.length; i++) {
            await component.checkPing(component.state.applications[i].id);
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.getApplications();
    }

    render() {
        return (<div></div>)
    }
}

export default Applications;
```

Comment: can you try adding a console.log inside your for loop to check how many times `checkPing` is being called ?

Comment: `applications.length` when it chooses to run, none any other time.

Comment: Why are you doing an `await component.setState({..})`. What happens when you remove `await` here.

Comment: You either need to move your for loop inside then block or you can use componentDidUpdate lifecycle hook. axios call is asynchronous and your for loop is currently not waiting for it to complete.

Comment: @inkredusk Because if I didn't applications would be empty, therefor no for loop iterations would be executed

Comment: @CodeThing it was in the then block originally.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment,

You either need to move your for loop inside then block or you can use componentDidUpdate lifecycle hook. axios call is asynchronous and your for loop is currently not waiting for it to complete.

Here is the example of using componentDidUpdate

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      applications: []
    };
  }

  async checkPing(applicationId) {
    console.log("pinging " + applicationId);
  }

  async getApplications() {
    var component = this;

    try {
        const response = await axios.get("./data.json");
        component.setState({ applications: response.data });
    } catch (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getApplications();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.applications.length; i++) {
      this.checkPing(this.state.applications[i].id);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>HERE</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

If you do not want to use componentDidUpdate then you can move for loop in then call like this.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      applications: []
    };
  }

  async checkPing(applicationId) {
    console.log("pinging " + applicationId);
  }

  async getApplications() {
    var component = this;

    try {
        const response = await axios.get("./data.json");
        component.setState({ applications: response.data });
        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          this.checkPing(response.data[i].id);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getApplications();
  }

  render() {
    return <div>HERE</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What @3limin4t0r mentioned in his answer is correct. We don't even need then blocks as we are awaiting the axios calls.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is probably that `setState()` will queue the state change and not directly apply it. `setState()` [does *not* return a promise](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v18.2.0/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js#L31-L69). Meaning that `await component.setState(...)` is useless. The only way to know when React is done updating the state is to use the [`componentDidUpdate()`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#componentdidupdate) hook.

An implementation of this hook, using your example might look like this:

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";

class Applications extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            error: null,
            applications: [],
        }
    }

    async checkPing(applicationId : bigint) {
        // ...
    }

    async getApplications() {
        // There is no need to work with `then()`, `catch()` or `finally()`
        // when we are within async context. We can use the respective
        // keywords instead.
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/applications');
            this.setState({ applications: response.data });
        } catch (error) {
            // handle error
            this.setState({ error });
        } finally {
            // always executed
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        }
    }

    // Content can also be placed in `componentDidMount()` instead of
    // its own method.
    async pingApplications() {
        for (const application of this.state.applications) {
            await this.checkPing(application.id);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getApplications();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.state.isLoading) return;
        if (this.state.error) return;

        this.pingApplications();
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoading, error, applications } = this.state;

        if (isLoading) return (
            <div className="loading">loading...</div>
        );

        if (error) return (
            <div className="error">{error.message}</div>
        );

        return (
            <div>content</div>
        );
    }
}

export default Applications;
```